# Stored procedure programming, with lists and loops in SQL Server issue

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have written my own quick comment/programming text, which is far from correct, but will illustrate what I want to do in the database by sql.

The hope is, that anybody with programming skills in SQL Server - stored procedures programming. Could assist me, to find out if this is even possible.

I have a little experience in Oracle´s PLSQL, so I know that its maybe possible.

I hope the example would explain it self, but if it doesn´t, please ask me to give a deep explanation of the sql/c#/comment example I have given below.

```
storedProcedure(firstWeek, lastWeek)
{

  Dictornary list = new OrderdDictornary(); //Key is a week, value is a list of tests

  //Run through each week.
  for(int i = firstWeek; i<=lastWeek; i++)
  {
     var queryList = 
     {
                //All in the database
            SELECT instrumentID
            FROM Tests
            GROUP BY InstrumentID

            EXCEPT

                //All that could be found in this week
            SELECT InstrumentID
            FROM Tests
            WHERE TimeCompleted = // In 'i' week (this week)
            GROUP BY InstrumentID
     }
     list.Add(i, queryList); //Key, Values
  }

  return list;
}
```

At last I would have a list of week keys, with values which are the right data sorted in weeks.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Okay I succeded. Did a While loop, to populate a global variable with datatype table, which I returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I succeded. Did a While loop, to populate a global variable with datatype table, which I returned.